# 415 Unsupported Media type JAXB in Spring

Tags: spring, jaxb, http-post

[image: My headers for POST setup]
[image: Main POST setup]

I'm a bit of stuck here. I am trying to POST from firefox's poster a small snippet of XML.

```xml
 <IntellexEvent>
 <RuleName>a rule name</RuleName>
 </IntellexEvent>
```

Simple enough, now my class for `IntellexEvent` is

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "IntellexEvent")
public class IntellexEvent {    
 // @XmlElement(name = "RuleName")
    private String RuleName;
    public String getRuleName()
    {
        return RuleName;
    }

    public void setRuleName(String RuleName)
    {
         this.RuleName = RuleName;
    }
```

}

My Controller is...

```java
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/cace/**")
public class CaceController 
{
    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;

    public CaceController()
    {

    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/cace/postXML", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Result postXML(@RequestBody String intellexEvent) throws Exception
    {   
        String temp = intellexEvent;

        Result result = new Result();
        result.setStatusCode(200);
        result.setSuccess(true);
            return result;
    }
```

}

--EDITED -- 
So here I have the @RequestBody as a String. What I wanted was for it to be automatically marshalled into an IntellexEvent.... As a string I am able to hit my backend on the POST, when I change the String to an IntellexEvent I get a 415 error.

I just want to be able to hit my backend, I've tried GETs, and I hit just fine, (I didn't include them in my controller here) what am I missing here? In spring-mvc-servlet.xml I've defined the jaxb2 marshaller. If you need more information just ask, thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I suspect this is more of a Spring issue than a JAXB one.  How have you configure your service regarding POST operations?

Comment: Copy and paste failure? The controller code is missing.

Comment: Yup, ill add that controller, and I have configured the service. I'll add the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the `Content-Type` header, which should be `application/xml`, this is for Spring-MVC to know that you are posting an xml. Further if you expect the response to be an xml, you have annotate your postXML method with `@ResponseBody` and have an `Accept` header of `application/xml`.

The postXML should look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cace/postXML", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Result postXML(@RequestBody IntellexEvent intellexEvent) throws Exception
```

One more thing which I noticed is that you will need to uncomment `@XmlElement(name = "RuleName")` with `ruleName` field otherwise the tag will end up being `<ruleName/>`

Comment: Ok, so in the post, I have the header Content-type:application xml... should i change the call to postXML to something like this

.... =RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public Result ......

?

Comment: This -- Along with setting up my IntellexEvent object correctly, helped me move on to another problem. Thanks very much I appreciate it. You wouldn't happen to know Why I'm getting a 406 Not Acceptable error on this post would you?

I've added the headers="Accept=application/xml") to the end of my RequestMethod.POST --- to no avail. Anymore help would be GREATLY appreciated. I have an IntellexEvent in the controller with all my properties correctly populated. I am creating a result and set the intellexEvent. After doing that I return my result. (This is were I'll get my 406.